# CodeIgniter's XSS Protection is removing <script> tags from user inputs... but I don't want it to!

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, script-tag

CodeIgniter is brilliant but I'm using it to develop a site where users need to be able to share their code for websites. Unfortunately, CodeIgniter has been doing the "right" thing by removing `<script>` tags from my user's inputs into the database, so when it's returned data looks like this:

[removed] User's data [removed]

However, I need my site to DISPLAY script tags but obviously not PARSE them. How can I get CodeIgniter or PHP to return `<script>` tags, but still sanitise them for the database and return them without them executing?

Thanks!

Jack

EDIT: By the way, it's not an option to use stuff like Markdown, everything has to output to copy-pastable code that could work with no modification somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want script tags displaying, but you don't want them rendered by the browser?

If that's the case, then I would use a simple `htmlspecialchars()` function to parse the code and convert all of the `<script>` tags to `&lt;script&gt;`.

I believe a somewhat equivalent function in CodeIgniter is `form_prep()`, from the Form helper, but how it behaves outside of form elements I don't know. So the `htmlspecialchars()` function should do just what you are asking.

I agree with Tom, above, in that you will need to disable global XSS filtering if you don't want your form elements having `script` tags stripped before they are saved.

Answer (score 3):

Im guessing you have XSS protection set to global in your config.php file change it to what i have below

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```